# CoreData NSManagedObject Swift subclass with reserved keyword

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a CoreData model that is already in use.  In that data model, one of the relationships uses a reserved keyword in Swift, "case" in this case.  When I use XCode to create subclass of the `NSManagedObject`, it gets an error because it tries to declare a `@NSManaged var case`, and "case" is a reserved keyword.

If I try to change the relationship name in the CoreData model, the app will not be able to read the previous database without migration.  Is there a way to get around this naming issue without doing a database migration or am I stuck with database migration?

Answer (score 1):

Back ticks will escape reserved words in swift 2. <strike>Not sure if that got trashed in swift 3.</strike>

`` var `case` ``

edit: this is still available in Swift 3.0